# Mathematical alphabetical equation

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

Assume that the following three equations hold true:

- $C \circ I \circ D \circ A = B$
- $O \circ K \circ M \circ G = C$
- $Y \circ A \circ B \circ C = D$

Find the right hand side of the following equation:

- $S \circ W \circ A \circ G =~ ?$

---

Hints:

1.

> Convert each letter to its corresponding numerical value.
>  E.g., $C \circ I \circ D \circ A = B$ is converted to $3 \circ 9 \circ 4 \circ 1 = 2$

2.

> Use mathematical operators to make above equations work out.

3.

> All the equations follow the same pattern. Just find a pattern, apply it to the last equation and find the result.

Comment: There is hardly any overlap between the letters in each equation, which means it is trivial to assign values to each letter and make S + W + A + G equal whatever you want.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, Yes.... there is a logic to solve this puzzle. This is an interview question. I took almost half an hour to solve it and of course after getting a hint..

Comment: Hint: Convert each alphabet to its corresponding numeric value...!! Then solve it using mathematical operators.

Comment: Would the question be more accurate if listed as $f(S,W,A,G)=?$ or is the usage of three operators significant?

Comment: Do the letters map to unique numbers (e.g. $B=2 \implies C \ne 2$)? Do all the circles represent the same operation (e.g. all multiplications, or all additions, etc)?

Comment: Yes, each alphabet maps to a unique number (i.e. A=1, B=2, C=3, ..., Z=26). You can use any possible mathematical operators to find a common pattern. The circle doesn't mean that it's going to replace by the same operator. Actually, in my original question, I had used "+" instead of a circle, and I had mentioned that here "+" doesn't mean an addition, but it represents a combination of letters. But the comment is removed in the edited version.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, yes, the use of "f(S,W,A,G) = ?" would justify more than using a circle or "+". And the second thing, it is not like that only three operators are possible to find a pattern. You can use "N" number of operators to perform the operation and find a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> $S \circ W \circ A \circ G = G$

**Explanation:** 
After plugging in the values $A=1,~B=2,~C=3,~\ldots,~Z=26$, each of the three
example equations $~~~\alpha\circ\beta\circ\gamma\circ\delta=\epsilon~~~$ follows the pattern

> $~~~(\alpha+\beta)/\gamma+\delta=\epsilon^2~~~~~$  respectively 
>  $~~~~~\epsilon=\sqrt{(\alpha+\beta)/\gamma+\delta}$

Indeed, the three given equations give us the following:

```
    C o I o D o A = B    yields     3 o  9 o  4 o  1 = 2
    O o K o M o G = C    yields    15 o 11 o 13 o  7 = 3
    Y o A o B o C = D    yields    25 o  1 o  2 o  3 = 4
```

One easily verifies that

> $(3+9)/4+1=2^2~~~$ and $~~~(15+11)/13+7=3^2~~~$ and $~~~(25+1)/2+3=4^2$

This then leads to

> $S\circ W\circ A\circ G=G~~~~~$ as $~(19+23)/1+7=7^2$

Comment: I don't know if i approve of you only reopening the question after you found the solution and then immediately posting it without giving others the chance.

Comment: There are clearly three operators in the question and you have used four in your solution. This is not valid.

Comment: @TheDarkTruth: I do not think that your accusation is justified. There were **four hours** between my vote to reopen this question and the submission of my solution. (You may check this in the review logs.)

Comment: @Gamow: Sorry i only saw your name amongst the 5 reopen votes. I'm not able to find any times as to when the respective vote was given. And since there were only 76 seconds between reopening and your solution post i arrived at an early conclusion.

Comment: @IanMcDonald: The problem statement says nothing about "three operators"; this is just your own private interpretation. The first version of the puzzle had plus-signs instead of the little circles, and explicitly stated that these plus-signs just indicate that the letters have to be combined some way.